# angularJS: undefined variable 'userName'

Tags: angularjs

This is my controller. I have two functions and I'm trying to pass variable available in one function inside the other. But I'm getting an undefined variable error.

I tried declaring variable globally but even after doing that, undefined error exists.
Can any one tell me where did I make mistake?

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('myApp.my', [])

        .factory('myService', function($http) {

            return {    
                getUserSessInfo: function() {
                    return $http.get('getUserInfo.php');
                },
                getNotifications: function(userName) 
                {
                    return $http.get('getMyNotifications.php?username='+userName);
                }
            };
        })

        .controller('myController', function($routeParams, myService) {
            var vm = this;
            var userName;

            //To get user session value
            myService.getUserSessInfo().success(function(data) {
                userName    = data.username;
                //vm.userName   = data.username;
            });

            //myService.getNotifications(vm.userName).success(function(data) {
            myService.getNotifications(userName).success(function(data) {
                vm.notifications = data;
            }); 

        });
})();
```

Comment: Which variable is undefined?

Comment: userName @Hopeful Llama

Comment: Amelia, i think you need to chain the function calls since they return promises.

Comment: Chaining? How can I do that? I'm new to angular. Are there any tutorials for that? @Jideobi Benedine Ofomah

Comment: @JideobiBenedineOfomah is correct. They are both asynchronous calls, so `getNotifications` is being fired before userName is defined.

Comment: How to do chaining? @Hopeful Llama

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(function() {

angular
    .module('myApp.my', [])

    .factory('myService', function($http) {

        return {    
            getUserSessInfo: function() {
                return $http.get('getUserInfo.php');
            },
            getNotifications: function(userName) 
            {
                return $http.get('getMyNotifications.php?username='+userName);
            }
        };
    })

    .controller('myController', function($routeParams, myService) {
        var vm = this;
        var userName;

        //To get user session value
        myService.getUserSessInfo().success(function(data) {
            userName    = data.username;
            myService.getNotifications(userName)
            .success(function(data) {
                vm.notifications = data;
                }); 
        });


    });
})();
```

like the person above mentioned, you need to make sure you have retrieved username from the server before using it inside getNotification() because it is an async call.

I suggest you put this call inside your router resolve block and inject the data (notification) into the controller, that way your username will always be defined.  even with my code above, it will be undefined initially until the request from back-end has been completed successfully

Answer (score 3):

If Jideobi Benedine Ofomah wants to post his answer, please mark his as correct since he answered before me, albeit as a comment.

As mentioned before, `getUserSessInfo` and `getNotifications` are asynchronous which means the code does not fire sequentially as it is read.

The easiest way to get the code functioning is to do the following:

```
 //To get user session value
 myService.getUserSessInfo().success(function(data) {
     userName    = data.username;

     myService.getNotifications(userName).success(function(data) {
         vm.notifications = data;
     });
 });
```

Because the anonymous fuctions are promises, it means they will only be executed once the response is received from the remote server. By moving the code like this, we are telling the code to `getNotifications` only when we have the response, and thus have the `userName` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
        myService.getNotifications(userName).success(function(data) {
            vm.notifications = data;
        });
```

This code is executed before the .success function is fired. Thats because .success function is a callback.

Put myService.getNotifications(userName) inside .success function of getUserSessInfo()

Answer (score 0):

```
myService.getUserSessInfo().success(function(data) {
  userName    = data.username;

  myService.getNotifications(userName).success(function(data) {
    vm.notifications = data;
  });

});
```

Add `getNotifications` function call within the `getUserSessInfo` function, so `userName` will be filled with required data before function call.

I think your issue is because of, calling the function before `userName` filled with required data.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to seperate those two methods & do your work, try the following:

1. create your value model.(`user-model.js`)

```
    var UserModel= function(){
    this.username='';
    }

    angular.module('myApp.my').value('UserModel',UserModel);
```

2. inject the model in service factory or in controller and update the model based on the value returned by first service call.

```
    angular.module('myApp.my')
        .controller('myController', function($routeParams, myService, UserModel) {
           var vm = this;
           //var userName;

           //To get user session value
        myService.getUserSessInfo().success(function(data) {
            UserModel.userName    = data.username;
        });

        myService.getNotifications(UserModel.userName).success(function(data)       {            vm.notifications = data;
         });
    });
```

Hope this helps.